# Convert textField to String and String to textField

Tags: java, android, string, textfield

I have a function that deletes an entry in a list when it is clicked.

```
entriesView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
    View arg1, int position, long id) {
        TodoEntry entryToRemove = (TodoEntry) parent
        .getItemAtPosition(position);

        ourAdapter.remove(entryToRemove);

        return true;
    }
});
```

I would like to change that function that entries are not deleted but edited when clicked long. I want to read the value of the entry (I have it in an array and can get the String with `entryToEdit.toString();`) and change the entry into a textfield which the user can edit. When it is edited the textfield should become an entry again.

Comment: sorry if I explained it too difficultly. I have the position and value of a TodoEntry object and I want to create a textfield at the same position instead of the entry with the entry's value. This text field should be editable. When editing is done, I want to convert the textfield back into a TodoEntry.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `String` try using the `toString()` method or have basic logic in your class with a get method to return the `String`. To create an `EditText`:

```
EditText edit = new EditText();
```

Then add it to your view, or:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_edit_text_id);
```

Then set the text:

```
edit.setText(YOUR_STRING_HERE);
```

If you are trying to set the `EditText` at the specific position in the `ListView` then you need to make a custom `Adapter`. Within the custom adapter class, you will need to override the `getView` method. With some logic you can display either an `EditText` or `TextView` appropriately.

Comment: Thank you, I get this so far but the EditText should not be displayed from the very beginning but at the moment when the Item is clicked. So it should not be visible before the Entry is being edited. But if I create a new EditText in the XML it is shown by default.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a dialog with a textField, and use the value in the action of the positive button in the listener and set the object with the new data.

Hope you get the idea.